# Вывод порядкового номера дочернего элемента ближайшего родителя MODX Revo pdoTools?

Tags: modx, revo, pdoresource, pdotools

Продолжаю изучать modx и pdoTools. У меня есть:

```
-Отец // id = 19
--Сын 1
---Внук 1
---Внук 2
---Внук 3
---Внук 4
--Сын 2
---Внук 1
---Внук 2
---Внук 3
---Внук 4
--Сын 3
---Внук 1
---Внук 2
---Внук 3
---Внук 4
```

Допустим я нахожусь на странице первого внука первого сына отца и тут хочу вывести номер этого внука вверху страницы. Как мне это сделать с помощью pdoTools или системными методами?

Потихоньку начинаю разбираться в pdoTools, но в голове каша иза-за кучи инфы пока что не уложилась по полочкам, поэтому прошу помощи. Что-то прочитал про **[[+idx]]** но вроде это не то.

```
[[pdoMenu?
    &parents=`19`
    &level=`0`
    &tpl=`@INLINE`
    &countChildren=`1`
]]
```

Comment: Первый внук второго отца тоже должен вернуть 1?

Comment: @Tunker да тоже) Только не отца, а сына - первый внук второго сына отца)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если принудительно ничего не меняете, то плейсхолдер modx [[+menuindex]] - позиция страницы в дереве

Comment: Везде возвращает 0. Вызвал так [[*menuindex]]

Comment: Пардон сам затупил, Ваш ответ помог, спасибо!

Comment: собственно `[[+idx]]` тоже самое должен выводить, если вы через `pdomenu` выводите то `[[+idx]]` - номер пункта в меню, причем это более корректно будет, если к примеру вы будете использовать сортировку по другому полю чем `menuindex`

Comment: почему ***menuindex*** всегда начинается 0, а не с 1? 0,1,2,3...

Comment: Так во многих языках первый элемент имеет индекс 0, я уже сказал, что лучше и правильнее конечно использовать [[+idx]] но если надо то можно так: [[+menuindex:add=` `1` `]]

Comment: я так понял не pdomenu, а pdoResources имеет метод ***idx***, но так и не въезжаю как вывести порядковый номер

Comment: `pdoMenu` тоже имеет idx только они немного разные, в `pdoResources` это номер по порядку из тех ресурсов, что отобраны для показа, в `pdoMenu` это номер начиная от родителя. Использовать как и все плейсхолдеры например:   &tpl=` `@INLINE <li>[[+idx]]. [[+menutitle]][[+wrapper]]</li>` `